# Sending message to Google Chat whenever a cell is updated

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a simple chat bot that would send a message through Google Chat whenever column B is updated.

The code I came up with works on Debug mode or whenever I click Run but doesn't send any message whenever I update the sheet.

Here's the code I used:

```
function onChange(e) {
  const url = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/63jRdUAAAAE/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=neEgxu9-2dMb_hioE_peuRwHhIigdsp7MBV1dLJX4cY"
//update sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

//get current cell
//  var currCell = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

//update range for ldap and text message
  var message = "@" + sheet.getRange("B"+lastRow).getValue() + " " + sheet.getRange("A"+lastRow).getValue();

  var ldap = sheet.getRange("B"+lastRow).getValue();

  if (ldap=="") {
    const options = {
      "method": "post",
      "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
      "payload": JSON.stringify({
        "text": message,
        "thread": {"threadKey": "THREAD_KEY_VALUE"}
      })
    }
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    console.log(response);  
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know of any triggers that respond to changes caused by formula's or other scripts except onChange other which responds to imports. I doubt that we will ever see them because they would attract the attention of those that are a part of DDOS attacks.

Comment: Hi FJ, if your code runs but fetch don't, may be is because only installed triggers can fetch external resources.

Comment: Thanks for checking guys!

I just used a button to trigger the Hangouts notification.